# Unable to pass decimal value in query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-query

Heyo! I have a spreadsheet for all of the servers I have with sites and their version numbers on them. I am wanting another sheet to pull the sites that are under a certain version number so I know what sites need to be updated. When doing so I get the following error.

```
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " <DECIMAL_LITERAL> ".6 "" at line 1, column 50. Was expecting one of: "and" ... "or" ... ")" ...
```

Here's my query:

```
=query({'Heyo1 - CLOUD'!A:G;Heyo2!A:G;Heyo3!A:G;Heyo4!A:G;'Heyo4 - VPS'!A:G;'Heyo5 - VPS'!A:G}, "Select * Where (Col2 = 'Wordpress' and Col4 < 3.9.6 or Col2 = 'Joomla' and Col4 < 3.8.7 ) order by Col2 DESC ")
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it me or your `=query...` syntax is incomplete/fcked? Like missing brackets

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski na the query is all good, not had a problem with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complaining about the `.6` because Google Spreadsheet thinks your query has an invalid decimal:

`Col4 < 3.9.6`

And also

`Col4 < 3.8.7`

But since these are version numbers, you'll need to compare these as strings (see the caveat below).

Based on your comments you can probably get away with the following:

```
=query({'Heyo1 - CLOUD'!A:G;Heyo2!A:G;Heyo3!A:G;Heyo4!A:G;'Heyo4 - VPS'!A:G;'Heyo5 - VPS'!A:G}, "Select * Where (Col2 = 'Wordpress' and Col4 < '3.9.6' or Col2 = 'Joomla' and Col4 < '3.8.7' ) order by Col2 DESC ")
```

Keep in mind that if, for whatever reason, you end up with a version number like `3.20.0` that it is considered smaller than `3.3.0` when comparing strings. If this happens you would probably need to have a custom function where you tokenize the version numbers by splitting the string by the period and process each element separately.

Comment: Yeh, it's a version number, any idea how I can convert it to text within the query?

Comment: Thinking about that now...it's going to get difficult when you have a version like `3.21.0` because lexically it's smaller than say `3.9.0`

Comment: That wont be to much of a problem as with Joomla and Wordpress once they hit x.x.9 they normally go to the next value

Comment: @Jordan cool, I just updated the answer. Give that a try, I think it'll work for you.

Comment: That's done it, thank you. Also, notice I was calling on the wrong column which didn't help...

Comment: @Jordan great, glad it worked! If you don't mind, could you please upvote and accept this answer?